# UIView respect uinavigationbar size storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, autolayout

I have this UIView, wich is supposed to be fullscreen, but in my uiviewcontroller, i have an uinavigation bar. If i put the UIView inside it, with the same size as the uiviewcontroller view, it ignores the 64px of the navigationbar, making it bigger than the screen.
Theres any way using constraints and auto-layout to configure it correctly?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the top constraint for the view you added is pinned to the top layout guide, not the superView.